# hide uitableview with swipe or gesture

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer

I am making navigation app on swift, and I have a half view - mapView, and a bottom half - tableView. I am looking for a way to hide tableView with down swipe(swiping top of tableView down, and it disappears. I found a way how to hide it with animation, but I don't know how to make this action with swipe, without any conflict with mapView. Any ideas or some advices?

Comment: Do you want to start swiping on the map to hide it too? Or just swipe on the `UITableView` to hide it?

Comment: Just swipe UiTableView to hide it, yeap, I have function to do this, but I don't know how to make it with  down swipe

Comment: Then show you function and I might be able to tell you what you are missing :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to create a `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` and have to add it to the `UITableView`.
Try the following:

```
let swipeGesture = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "hideTableView:") //do that animation to hide the UITableView
swipeGesture.direction = .Down //Swiping down may come into conflict w/ the UITableView itself if it is scrollable, check it out.
tableView.addGestureRecognizer(swipeGesture)
```

The selector `func` looks the follwing:

```
func hideTableView(sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
    //do hidingAnimation
}
```

Comment: I ll try it in a few minutes, it won't conflict with tableView scroll?
how to right make a selector function: func hideTableView() {} ?

Comment: I am not sure whether it will conflict, but I think so if the `UITableView` is scrollable. See my edit for the selection function.

Comment: I'v done everything like you said, but selector method isn't calling after swipe down

Comment: Did you add it properly to the `UITableView`?